# Why out of gas if it doesn't consume that much in the end?

Tags: transactions, gas, evm, gas-limit, out-of-gas

I tried modify gas limit to a number I checked it should be enough to run transfer on USDT (62,800) but failed with "out of gas" error. When I send another transaction without modifying again it went through with consumed even lesser gas (58,397).

Why it failed in the first place if there's enough gas with the custom lower gas limit?

Below are screenshots for failing txn and success txn. Removed some information for privacy.
[image: failed]
And successed txn:
[image: success]

Answer (score 0):

Are those the same tx (same params i mean)? Theres a few reason why gas usage can vary. Typically, sending usdt to an address that has a 0 balance in usdt is about 18000 gas more expensive than sending to an address that already has a balance. My guess would be thats what's happening here.

Comment: The parameters are same, sending to the exact same address with exact same amount at almost same time.

Answer (score 0):

Refunds for a contract execution are returned after the transaction was completed. It could be that the transaction needs more than 62800 gas, you receive the difference as refund.